# Android Lollipop Toolbar Invert Colors

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Am using Android L v21 Support library for Android L's Toolbar-ActionBar. I want the items in the toolbar to be white in color. i.e. Navigation Back button, Action Buttons, Overflow Actions. If I use the dark version as the application theme(Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) then all the toolbar items are shown in white. But when I use the light version (Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) for the application all the toolbar items are shown dark. I want to use the light theme and want to make the toolbar to be show in white.

I have used activity.setTitleTextColor() to change the title's text color but not sure how to change the color for the rest.

[image: Android L Toolbar]

SOLUTION:

Thanks to @ianhanniballake

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

Comment: help me for how to add action1 & action2 item in toolbar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [AppCompat v21 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) under Styling:

> Styling of Toolbar is done differently to the standard action bar, and is set directly onto the view.

With the example of:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

Note the `app:theme` attribute which sets the action bar to use light color text / styling (`ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` does the opposite).

Comment: help me for how to add action1 & action2 item in toolbar